# Redirect payments in backend

Tags: payment, backend, payment-gateway

Is it possible to have redirect payments in the backend? And what is the workflow in this case?

My custom payment methods uses the method authorize() to make an authorization request to a payment gateway and sometimes, the payment will require a redirect afterwards (for example for paypal or for credit card 3D secure payments).

This works fine in the frontend, but is it possible to integrate this workflow also into the backend?

The background of this is that the shop owner wants to create orders when customers call on the phone and he wants all the payment methods we programmed in the frontend.

Does anyone have experience for this? Is it possible at all and what are the necessary steps to do so?

Comment: 3DS payment methods (which I *hate* with the energy of a thousand suns) are not suitable for admin workflow as the authentication passphrase must be known only to the cardholder. Better to process these via merchant virtual terminal and create a paid order in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is a reasonable solution for this. This workflow would be possible:

1. Place order in the admin by only selecting your payment method (no data)
2. Get redirected to payment gateway after placing the order. At this point, the order is created on Magento in a "pending"/similar state
3. Fill in payment details, get back to the orders screen.

Now this scenario does not account for a failed payment attempt. If you enter the wrong data, your order would still be in the pending state. You could create a "pay" link in the order management screen to let the admin retry with another card. The exact implementation for this depends on the payment gateway, but it is in principle the same as when doing the whole process in the frontend, only with different urls.

If you are looking to not create the order at all unless payment is successful, this is not possible, or at least not reasonably possible.

These being said, I usually advice my clients against trying to use redirect-type payment methods in the backend. The right way to do it is either switch to a gateway that uses silent post or just do the orders in the frontend.

Comment: Well said, this should suffice as an answer if an iframe workflow is incorporated for the admin order process, much as it would be in the frontend, and noting that 3DS worflow is not possible for admin-based orders (ref my comment on OP).